# Nodes not printed on x-axis

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following code instructs TikZ to draw the graph described by the equation `y=\frac{\sqrt{x^{2}-25}}{\sqrt{x-5}}`.  (This graph looks like `y=\sqrt{x+5}`.) I specifically want two numbers, `-5` and `5`, on the x-axis to be labeled.  Without specifying scaling, the y-axis is magnified much more than the x-axis and the graph does not resemble `y=\sqrt{x+5}`.To get the same scaling for both axes while keeping the width and height unchanged, I used the optional command `set axis equal`. Since the function is a positive function, the part of the Cartesian plane that is drawn almost includes nothing below the x-axis. So, the labels for `-5` and `5` are only partially set. (You have to look carefully to see any part of these two numbers.) How do I artificially extend the y-axis downwards a bit ... at least so that the labels `-5` and `5` are drawn on the graph?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textwidth}{6.1in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textheight}{9in}

%http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf

\begin{document}

\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=4in,axis equal image,
          xmax=26,ymax=7,
          axis lines=middle,
          restrict y to domain=-3:6.5,
          enlargelimits,
          axis line style={shorten >=-0.25cm,shorten <=-0.25cm,latex-latex},
          ticklabel style={fill=white},
          extra x ticks={-5,5},
          %extra x tick style={grid=none}
]
\pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
\addplot[domain=5:26,mark=none,samples=201] {sqrt(x + 5)} node[fill=white, below left, yshift=-3pt]{$\scriptstyle y=\frac{\sqrt{x^{2}-25}}{\sqrt{x-5}}$};
\addplot[domain=-6:5,dashed,thin,mark=none,samples=201] {sqrt(x + 5)};

\draw [densely dashed] (5,3.16227766) -- (5,0) node[below]{$5$};
\draw[fill] (-5,0) circle [radius=1.5pt] node[below]{$-5$};
\draw [fill=white] (5,3.16227766) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}


\end{document}
```

Comment: How can `(x^2-25)/sqrt(x-5)` become similar to `sqrt(x+5)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you put `\pgfplotsset{ticks=none}` after `\begin{axis}`, you're switching off all tick marks, including the `extra x ticks` that you set in the `axis` options.

If you only want to place tick marks at some selected coordinates, simply set `xtick={-5, 5}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=4in,axis equal image,
          xmax=26,ymax=7,
          axis lines=middle,
          restrict y to domain=-3:6.5,
          enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
          axis line style={latex-latex},
          ticklabel style={fill=white},
          xtick={-5,5}
]
\addplot[domain=5:26,mark=none,samples=201] {sqrt(x + 5)} node [below left, yshift=-3pt]{$\scriptstyle{y}=\frac{x^{2} - 25}{\sqrt{x - 5}}$};
\addplot[domain=-6:5,dashed,thin,mark=none,samples=201] {sqrt(x + 5)};

\draw [densely dashed] (5,3.16227766) -- (5,0);
\draw [fill] (-5,0) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw [fill=white] (5,3.16227766) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are there tick marks on the y-axis by default? In case I decide not to have the tick marks of 5 and 10 on the y-axis, what code will remove them?

Comment: @user143462: You can switch off the tick marks for the y axis by setting `ytick=\empty`

Comment: How can `(x^2-25)/sqrt(x-5)` become similar to `sqrt(x+5)`?

Comment: @ohmyghost: Simple

Comment: I think you did not realize  that the square root is missing in your label. It should be `$\frac{\sqrt{x^2-25}}{\sqrt{x-5}}$`.

Answer (score 0):

A PSTricks solution using the [`pst-plot`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-plot) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-plot}

\newcommand*\Label[1]{
  \psline(!#1 #1 5 add sqrt)(#1,0)
  \psdot(#1,0)
  \uput[270](#1,0){$#1$}
}

\begin{document}

\psset{
  unit = 0.26,
  algebraic
}
\begin{pspicture}(-8,-3)(36.4,13.5)
% points
\def\pointA{-5 }
\def\pointB{5 }
\def\pointC{30 }
  % drawing
  \psaxes[
    Dy = 5,
    labels = y,
    ticks = y
  ]{->}(0,0)(-8,-3)(35,12)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
  \psplot{\pointB}{\pointC}{sqrt(x + 5)}
 \psset{
   linestyle = dotted
 }
  \psplot{\pointA}{\pointB}{sqrt(x + 5)}
  \Label{\pointA}
  \Label{\pointB}
  \psdot[dotstyle = Bo](!\pointB \pointB 5 add sqrt)
  \uput[90](!\pointC \pointC 5 sub sqrt 1 add){%
    $\displaystyle y = \frac{\sqrt{x^{2} - 25}}{\sqrt{x - 5}}$%
  }
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

All you have to do is choose the values of `\pointA` (left-most x-value), `\pointB` (dotted and solid curves meet), and `\pointC` (label point and end point for solid curve). The drawing will then be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: How can `(x^2-25)/sqrt(x-5)` become similar to `sqrt(x+5)`?

Comment: @Ohmyghost No idea but that is what the OP says in the question. I will say that it's `(x+5)\sqrt{x-5}`.

Comment: So the label in your output should be `$y=\sqrt(x^2-25)/\sqrt(x-5)$`.

Comment: @Ohmyghost Ohhh! I missed the square root. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I am making a test for a Business Calculus class.  I was emphasizing functions that have restricted domains. The example that I presented in class was that the graph of the "messy looking" function y=(x^{2}-4)/(x-2) looks like the line y=x+2 except at 2.  This "messy looking" function that I wanted graphed looks like a horizontal shift of the square root function except for an interval, not just a point.  I thought it was an interesting variation.  It also requires students to know the algebraic properties of radicals.

Answer (score 0):

Correcting the existing answers and question with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\def\f{sqrt(x+5)}

\begin{document}
\begin{psgraph}[Dy=5,ticks=y,labels=y]{->}(0,0)(-7,-1)(12,11){12cm}{8cm}
    \psset{algebraic,plotpoints=150,linecolor=red}
    \psplot[linestyle=dashed,arrows=*-]{-5}{5}{\f}
    \psplot[arrows=o-]{5}{12}{\f}
    \psxTick(-5){-5}
    \psxTick(5){5}
    \uput[135](*10 {\f}){$\displaystyle y=\frac{\sqrt{x^2-25}}{\sqrt{x-5}}$}    
\end{psgraph}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What's happening at 5?

Comment: @percusse: Nothing happens.